# Can I use Restful Webservices with Hadoop Mapreduce program?

Tags: rest, hadoop

Can I use the Restful Webservices in the reducer of the mapreduce program in order to store the reducer output into mongodb.Can any one please suggest me.

Thanks, in advance

Comment: Can anyone please suggest me regarding this issue

Comment: Anyone please guide me ....